# Multi-Scenario Gurobi Python Output

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, python, gurobi

I have an lp and am trying to solve multiple scenarios at once. One of my scenarios is infeasible though this is not the issue.

[image]

For some reason, when I print m.status, both solutions have a status of 2 (Optimal) and the lp files are identical, despite me having changed the rhs in scenario 1. It looks like the changes I made in scenario 1 follow through to the solver but I cannot physically see them in the lp file and the model status seems to be incorrect. If I run scenario 1 by itself, the status prints out correctly as 4 (Infeasible) but the lp file still doesn't reflect the changes I made.

Has anyone experienced this before and is there anything I can do to correct this issue?

Comment: what's your m.ScenNName for scenario 1? Is it 'Optimal Production'

Comment: Yes and scenario 0 is 'Base Model'

Comment: check this pls: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360061615372-Multi-scenario-returns-infinity-objective-value-for-some-feasible-scenarios. It seems regardless of any infeasible scenario, if Gurobi finds an optimal scenario, the model status turns Optimal.

Comment: Very odd, the lp file issue was a conditional statement bug in my code, figured that one out. The model status is still optimal for both scenarios so that makes sense. Seems like the bug was not resolved as the response mentioned it would be. Thank you!